# How to select the first element of an object in javascript on IE8 without using []?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, selector

I'm fighting with IE8 and the `flashcanvas.js` plugin trying to capture a signature.

The [demo](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/require-drawn/) works fine on IE8, but since I'm using a bunch of other plugins including requireJS, I'm running into some kind of problem on IE8.

I have nailed it down to this:

```
function onReadyStateChange() {
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    document.detachEvent(ON_READY_STATE_CHANGE, onReadyStateChange);

    var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName(CANVAS);

    // => returns 1 in IE8 debugger
    console.log( canvases.length )
    // => returns objectHTMLCollection
    console.log( canvases )

    for (var i = 0, n = canvases.length; i < n; ++i) {
        console.log(" run "+i)

        // => this produces an error...
        console.log( canvases[i])

        // trigger
        FlashCanvas.initElement(canvases[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it's not working, but `canvases[i]` throws an `[object HTMLUnknownElement]` error.

**Question**:
Any idea what might be the cause? As a workaroud, how could I select the first element of my `objectHTMLCollection` without using `[]` and staying in Javascript!

I have also tried adding an `id` to the canvas element or select it by class (using Jquery). Same result, `length=1`, select=forget it.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**:
I'm requesting plugins like this from my main app controller:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#basket', function(e, data){  

    // signaturePad
    var signIt = $('.signatureWrapper');
    if ( signIt.length > 0 && signIt.jqmData('bound') != true ) {
        signIt.jqmData('bound', true);

        require(['services/signature/app'], function (App) {
        App.render({target: signIt, drawOnly: true });
            });
        };
```

This calls an `app.js` file, which defines all dependencies required and once everything has loaded, fire the plugin:

```
define([  'services/signature/app'
        , 'services/signature/jquery.signaturepad.min'
        , 'services/signature/json2.min'
        , 'services/signature/flashcanvas'
        ], function( app, signature, json2, flashcanvas ) {

    function render(parameters) {
        parameters.target.signaturePad({ drawOnly:parameters.drawOnly });
        };
        return {
            render:render
            };  
        });
```

So, I'm wasting an http-request for `flashcanvas.js` when I don't really need it. But all files are loaded allright, I believe...

Comment: Are you properly including the IE work around JavaScript files correctly? Show your basic markup for the script includes.

Comment: @epascarello: uhm. No idea what you mean. I can show you me requireJS require/define. 1 sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you adding the canvas element to the DOM? Since IE8 doesn't support the canvas element, you need to create it dynamically and append it to the DOM, as shown in the [FlashCanvas docs](http://flashcanvas.net/docs/usage)

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.getElementById("target").appendChild(canvas);
if (typeof FlashCanvas != "undefined") {
    FlashCanvas.initElement(canvas);
}
```

Comment: ah. this could be it. I have it hardcoded in the source. Thanks! Trying this.

Comment: ok. Nothing happens, but no error = "good start in IE8 speak :-D"

Comment: Most of the time the docs or FAQs is everything you need ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Array document.getElementsByName(String balise)
http://www.toutjavascript.com/reference/reference.php?iref=156

You wrote :

```js
var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName(CANVAS);
```

Are you sure CANVAS is a String ? Maybe you want to write

```js
var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS");
```

Comment: valid i++. Both the i++ and CANVAS are in the actual plugin code. Let's see.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about the ++i thing. I noticed that the variable isn't updated until the end of the iteration anyway. Something I didn't know.

Comment: ok for i++ (I'll delete this in my answer so) but when I try document.getElementsByTagName(CANVAS) in my IE8, CANVAS variable isn't defined... but it is ok went I try "CANVAS"

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the collection to an array:

var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( canvases );